# OpenLayers using exceed len on vector styles

Tags: openlayers

I have a text inside a style which fits inside a vector polygon.

On small polygons the text disappears (map is zoomed in max) so  I am trying to set exceed len to true based on [this example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-labels.html).

How can I use this within my style?

```
let style_selected = function (feature, resolution) {
let getParcel2 = feature.get("parcel_nbr")+"";
return new ol.style.Style({
  fill: new ol.style.Fill({
  color: '#5fba6a38'
}),
 stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
    color: 'red',
    width: 3
  }),
  text: new ol.style.Text({
    text: getParcel2,
    font: '4em Calibri,sans-serif',
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
    color: 'white'
    }),
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: 'green',
      width: 5
    })
  })
});
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set `ol.style.Text` option `overflow` to `true` to allow text to exceed the width of the polygon:

```
text: new ol.style.Text({
  text: getParcel2,
  font: '4em Calibri,sans-serif',
  fill: new ol.style.Fill({
    color: 'white'
  }),
  stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
    color: 'green',
    width: 5
  }),
  overflow: true
})
```